# Easiest way to do URL rewrite in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .htaccess

I have a blog that I have built. It uses a web api in c# .NET.

If you click here: http://www.judsondesigns.com/api/blogapi/17

You will see it return an entry from the server. How can I easily rewrite the url to use the blog title instead of the ID?

So instead you can access it via: http://www.judsondesigns.com/api/blogapi/my_blog_tite_here

I have done this with isapi rewrites in the past on linux, but wasnt clear how to in .NET. I have heard different way but would like the less is more approach here. Thanks in advance. -Judson

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is create a custom `RouteBase`. [This code review post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6543/16380) is a good place to start.

The jist of it is:

```
public class MyRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // parse url and turn into route
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(
        RequestContext requestContext,
        RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        // create url from route
    }
}
```

Which you then register along with any other routes like

```
routes.Add(new MyRoute());
```

Comment: Great answer, but it should be noted that routing is different (better) than actual [URL rewriting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net).

Answer (score 1):

By editing the route configuration:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{blogTitle}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", blogTitle = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

or rewrite the action to use the name instead and using a named parameter
    http://www.judsondesigns.com/api/blogapi/?blogtitle=my_blog_tite_here

Comment: Great answer, but it should be noted that routing is different (better) than actual [URL rewriting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net).

Comment: Why are these better than using the web config options that I have seen after adding packages.